# wxgrid SetCellvalue and Wordwrap

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

I have a grid with 3 columns. The first column is being populated with the multiple files that I am importing and writes to the appropriate rows based upon the number of files. This works fine as long as wordwrap is not enabled. I am having problem when trying to populate the second column, this column also allows user to select multiple files but I want the files to be comma separated for each row . For example If I imported 3 files to first column so I have 3 rows of data in column A. Next I am trying to select 5 files for column B then for each row, I need to have a list of 5 files.

Second problem is with the wordwrap feature. I would like Column B and Column C to be Word Wrapped to certain Column size but I am having trouble doing it. If we use the wordwrap feature then both column and row need to be adjusted accordingly just like it happens in excel.

The following is the code.

```
import wx
import wx.grid
from wx.lib import wordwrap

def create(parent):
    return Frame1(parent)

[wxID_FRAME1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON2, wxID_FRAME1GRID1,
 wxID_FRAME1PANEL1,
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(5)]

class Frame1(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
        # generated method, don't edit
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_FRAME1, name='', parent=prnt,
              pos=wx.Point(394, 306), size=wx.Size(835, 372),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='Frame1')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(819, 334))

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(id=wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, name='panel1', parent=self,
              pos=wx.Point(0, 0), size=wx.Size(819, 334),
              style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1,
              label='Import to Column A', name='button1', parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(88, 16), size=wx.Size(152, 23), style=0)
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On_Button1_Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1)

        self.grid1 = wx.grid.Grid(id=wxID_FRAME1GRID1, name='grid1',
              parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(16, 64), size=wx.Size(776, 208),
              style=0)
        self.grid1.SetAutoLayout(False)

        self.button2 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON2,
              label='Import to Column B', name='button2', parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(256, 16), size=wx.Size(136, 23), style=0)
        self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On_Button2_Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON2)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)

    def On_Button1_Button(self, event):
        #event.Skip()
        filenames = []
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose  Files", ".", "","Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt", wx.MULTIPLE)
        try:
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                inputfilenames = dlg.GetPaths()
                gridheaderlist = ["File Name","Files to be Formatted","Other User Defined Options"]
                if self.grid1.GetNumberCols() == 0:
                    self.grid1.CreateGrid(len(inputfilenames),len(gridheaderlist))
                    for i in range(len(gridheaderlist)):
                        self.grid1.SetColLabelValue(i,gridheaderlist[i])
                        wordwrap.wordwrap(self.grid1.SetColLabelValue(i,gridheaderlist[i]),self.grid1.GetColSize(i),wx.ClientDC(self.panel1),breakLongWords=True)
                    for i in range(len(inputfilenames)):
                        self.grid1.SetCellValue(i,0,inputfilenames[i])
                else:
                    LastUsedRow = self.grid1.GetNumberRows()
                    self.grid1.InsertRows(LastUsedRow,len(inputfilenames))
                    for i in range(len(inputfilenames)):
                        self.grid1.SetCellValue(i+LastUsedRow,0,inputfilenames[i])
        finally:
            if self.grid1.GetNumberRows() >= 1:
                self.grid1.AutoSizeColumn(0, 1)
            dlg.Destroy()

    def On_Button2_Button(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        global forfiles
        forfiles = []
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose  Formatting Files", ".", "","Formatting Files (*.xls)|*.xls", wx.MULTIPLE)
        forfiles = dlg.GetPath()
        if len(forfiles) > 0:
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                    temp_files= dlg.GetPaths()
                    for d in range(len(temp_files)):
                            forfiles.append(temp_files[d])
            dlg.Destroy()
            for i in range(self.grid1.GetNumberRows()):
                self.grid1.SetCellValue(i,1,forfiles)
        if len(forfiles) == 0:
            try:
                if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                    forfiles = dlg.GetPath()
            finally:
                if self.grid1.GetNumberRows() >= 1:
                    self.grid1.AutoSizeColumn(1, 1)
                dlg.Destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = create(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Also, when I am resizing my frame, my grid doesn’t resize with the frame. Is there a way we can accomplish it.

Comment: is this from BoaConstructor or something? the "don't edit" comment looks like a RAD tool. i was going to respond to some of this, mostly to say 'use sizers' but if you are using a RAD tool, you want to do it there, not by editing code.

Comment: Yes I used boa constructor. But u can edit it to fix the issue. The command button definitions can be edited.

Comment: I don't really know boa. I mostly do my GUIs by hand. But in general if there is a way to use sizers in Boa, that's what you want. If there isn't, maybe try http://visualwx.altervista.org/indexen.php ? also hasn't been updated in a long time, and i used it for C++ code, but afaik it works with sizers and also does python...

Comment: even though I used boa, the one I having problems is with wxgrid which is common even if we use sizers unless I am mistaken. I am having problem with writing the data to wxgrid cells.

Answer (score 0):

I solved part of the issue with wxgrid setting values in a cell. Here is the updated Code.

```
import wx
import wx.grid
from wx.lib import wordwrap

def create(parent):
    return Frame1(parent)

[wxID_FRAME1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON2, wxID_FRAME1GRID1,
 wxID_FRAME1PANEL1,
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(5)]

class Frame1(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
        # generated method, don't edit
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_FRAME1, name='', parent=prnt,
              pos=wx.Point(394, 306), size=wx.Size(835, 372),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='Frame1')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(819, 334))

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(id=wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, name='panel1', parent=self,
              pos=wx.Point(0, 0), size=wx.Size(819, 334),
              style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1,
              label='Import to Column A', name='button1', parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(88, 16), size=wx.Size(152, 23), style=0)
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On_Button1_Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1)

        self.grid1 = wx.grid.Grid(id=wxID_FRAME1GRID1, name='grid1',
              parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(16, 64), size=wx.Size(776, 208),
              style=0)
        self.grid1.SetAutoLayout(False)

        self.button2 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON2,
              label='Import to Column B', name='button2', parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(256, 16), size=wx.Size(136, 23), style=0)
        self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On_Button2_Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON2)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)

    def On_Button1_Button(self, event):
        #event.Skip()
        filenames = []
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose  Files", ".", "","Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt", wx.MULTIPLE)
        try:
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                inputfilenames = dlg.GetPaths()
                gridheaderlist = ["File Name","Files to be Formatted","Other User Defined Options"]
                if self.grid1.GetNumberCols() == 0:
                    self.grid1.CreateGrid(len(inputfilenames),len(gridheaderlist))
                    for i in range(len(gridheaderlist)):
                        self.grid1.SetColLabelValue(i,gridheaderlist[i])
                        #wordwrap.wordwrap(self.grid1.SetColLabelValue(i,gridheaderlist[i]),self.grid1.GetColSize(i),wx.ClientDC(self.panel1),breakLongWords=True)
                    for i in range(len(inputfilenames)):
                        self.grid1.SetCellValue(i,0,inputfilenames[i])
                else:
                    LastUsedRow = self.grid1.GetNumberRows()
                    self.grid1.InsertRows(LastUsedRow,len(inputfilenames))
                    for i in range(len(inputfilenames)):
                        self.grid1.SetCellValue(i+LastUsedRow,0,inputfilenames[i])
        finally:
            if self.grid1.GetNumberRows() >= 1:
                self.grid1.AutoSizeColumn(0, 1)
            dlg.Destroy()

    def On_Button2_Button(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        global forfiles, test
        forfiles = []
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose  Formatting Files", ".", "","Formatting Files (*.xls)|*.xls", wx.MULTIPLE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            forfiles = dlg.GetPaths()
        dlg.Destroy()
        if len(forfiles) > 0:
            for d in range(len(forfiles)):
                if d == 0:
                    test = forfiles[d]
                else:
                    test = test + '\n' + forfiles[d]              
            for i in range(self.grid1.GetNumberRows()):
                self.grid1.SetCellValue(i,1,test)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = create(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

I Still haven't figured out the problem with wordwrap feature.